# Why is NetworkError thrown in muted error mode?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I found this case interesting in [whatwg](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#calling-scripts) specification:

> 1. If evaluationStatus is an abrupt completion, then:
>
>    1. If rethrow errors is true and script's muted errors is false, then:
>
>       1. Clean up after running script with settings.
>       2. Rethrow evaluationStatus.[[Value]].
>    2. If rethrow errors is true and script's muted errors is true, then:
>
>       1. Clean up after running script with settings.
>       2. **Throw a "NetworkError" DOMException.**
>    3. Otherwise, rethrow errors is false. Perform the following steps:
>
>       1. Report the exception given by evaluationStatus.[[Value]] for script.
>       2. Clean up after running script with settings.
>       3. Return evaluationStatus.

I’m interested in how you could understand: `Throw a "NetworkError" DOMException.` Actually, who understands why an error is raised here if we have all errors muted, and why is this error raised? What is her reason for appearing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** This is a Same-Origin Policy (SOP) security restriction.

The links in that section take you to more info. Step 1.2 has [a link to here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#muted-errors) that states:

> A boolean which, if true, means that error information will not be provided for errors in this script. This is used to mute errors for cross-origin scripts, since that can leak private information.

And if you look at the spec, the `muted errors` flag is set for a given script when it is loaded from an origin that is considered cross-origin from the one loading the script.

The core issue is that `<script>` (and `importScripts`) are allowed to load an execute code from arbitrary origins. *However*, if you load a script from a cross-origin location, it is important that if it fails to load, that you not be able to know *why* it failed, for security reasons. Similarly, if you ran `fetch()` to load a remote URL, you are very limited in what you are able to know about the response data you got for the request.

As for *why*, this behavior is most often encountered when using `onerror` handlers. [The `onerror` MDN docs have a note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#Notes) which leads to [Firefox bug 363897](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363897) and [this blog post describing the security issue](https://blog.jeremiahgrossman.com/2006/12/i-know-if-youre-logged-in-anywhere.html).

The core of the issue is, browsers have careful restrictions on what information you are and aren't allowed to get from a cross-origin request. If you are able to load a cross-origin URL and then intercept the exception, you could potentially gain information about the content of the URL being loaded, which is what the Same-Origin Policy aims to prevent. The blog post there has more info.

Comment: That is, the term muted errors as part of the whatwg specification is used exclusively for CORS. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Each script that is loaded will have this boolean flag to decide how errors from it are treated.